# manually testing classes with testng and jdk1.4

Tags: java, testng, jdk1.4

I work on a maven project that needs to be jdk1.4 compliant. Our testng classes use the pseudo-javadoc comments to define tests.

```
/**
 * @testng.test
 */
```

In Netbeans, the right-click menu works fine to run tests. In Eclipse, my collegues tell me it does not work and the test class is not found. So I've been trying to add a main() to the test classes, using something along the lines of

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses( new Class[]{MyTestClass.class} );
testng.run();
```

But when I do, I get the following result:

```
Command line suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

So, basically, tests are not found, which does not surprise me, as something needs to parse the javadoc and I don't see how it could happen here. Has anyone had a similar problem? How did you get around it so that individual classes can be tested easily in Eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried the testng eclipse plugin: http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html ? To quote: "Once you have selected one of these launches, you can also choose ... whether TestNG should run in 1.4 or 1.5 mode."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG stopped supporting JDK 1.4 a while ago.

Comment: Ok, but that should mean I can use an older version of testng for it to work, no? What version should I be using? 5.X? 4.X?

Comment: I wouldn't even bother, frankly, it was a while ago.